# Connect to Sqlplus using processbuilder

Tags: java, oracle, automation, sqlplus

`enter code here`I am trying to connect Oracle SQL Developer using `sqlplus` using Java code by `processbuilder`, as I am involed in automation of SQL queries.

We are able to connect to database, but I want to commit the query only when the spool file does not contains any error.

How can I connect to `sqlplus` in the same session so as to commit the query as well. I have used `autocommit` as off previously using:
`writer.append("SET EXITCOMMIT OFF;");`

Now I want to commit when the spool file has no error.
Can anyone help me in this?

Thanks in Advance!

```
// commitToComment
 replaceCommitToComment.CommitToComment(path);

try{
  BufferedReader read= new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));
  ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
  String dataRow = read.readLine(); 
  while (dataRow != null){
  list.add(dataRow);
  dataRow = read.readLine(); 
  }

  FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(path); //same as your file name above          so that it will replace it
  System.out.println("SPOOL FILE READY");
  writer.append("SPOOL D:/Bot_Trax_data/"+Logfile);

  writer.append(System.lineSeparator());
  writer.append("alter session set nls_date_format = 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS';");

  for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){
   writer.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
   writer.append((CharSequence) list.get(i));
 }
   writer.append(System.lineSeparator());
   writer.append("SPOOL OFF;");
   writer.append(System.lineSeparator());
   writer.append("SET EXITCOMMIT OFF;");
   writer.append(System.lineSeparator());
   writer.append("EXIT;");  
    and calling  readFile(path, toRun); 


        System.out.println("inside sqlconnection");
            Process process = processBuilder.start();
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
            String currentLine = null;
            while ((( currentLine = in.readLine()) != null)  ) {                    
                System.out.println(" "  + currentLine);
            }     
            in.close();
            process.destroy();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch(Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
```

Comment: sql developer is a client. sqlplus is a client. you don't connect TO them. you use one or the other to connect to Oracle Database. you should be able to issue commits on your connection in your java code directly

Comment: Thankyou for your reply! Yes I have used sqlplus with oracle 11g as client to connect to oracle database. I am able to commit my query as well. But I want to validate if my query gives no error then only I want to commit. For this I require to make another connection which does not give me the commit result due to different session.

Comment: Just start another sqlplus session; you do not need a different client.

Comment: Starting another session does not commit the query.I am calling a text file having just commit; statement if no error occurs. Please assist

Comment: i don't understand your question. you have to commit your work in the session you did the work, you can't commit it from somewhere else

Comment: We don't commit queries, we commit transactions. It is hard for us to help you if you can't explain clearly what it is you want to achieve. Using terminology correctly is part of that. Please post some sample code to help us understand your scenario.

Comment: It is a part of Automation, we have to commit the transaction anyhow but by automating it. I used the code above that creates spool file of the query after commenting all the commits first,and then connecting to database.Now I want to commit the transaction only after checking first it has no error

Comment: I want my transaction to be committed only when no error occurs else it should rollback the transaction. Can anyone help me in this?